# How we can assign class name in partial page

Tags: sxa

I created a page design that has 3 partial designs:

[image]

How can I add a css class for each separate component row splitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to set class for the whole column/row splitter rendering.

You can set classes only for placeholders inside (I added `container-gray-background` class to the first column):

[image]

You could achieve that by adding another wrapper around group of renderings.

You would have to put everything in a **Container**. You can assign classes to this rendering.

Then nest everything inside (in this case my container has `container-color-background` class, but this can be anything you like).

[image]

Comment: Hi Alan, have you added the class container-gray-background to placeholders through the creative exchange? I am looking for a way to directly add the class name to my placeholders inside the column splitter, so the front-end team just need to use the css selector on the class to do styling. Do you have any hints?

Comment: @MukeshBhojwani I don't think I used CE fo that.